# Configuring number of servers in Jmeter simulation

Tags: networking, jmeter

I would like to run a network simulation on an increasing number of clients (within a specified range) against a server. I would like to fix the number of client request and graph a response time graph as users are added to the simulation. I would like to repeat the simulation with an increasing number of servers to illustrate that the response time will improve as servers are added.

I have found how I could increase my thread count/number of clients over the simulation but can't seem to figure out how to increase the number of servers the clients will be using

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you need to conduct a [scalability test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scalability_testing) and measure the [scalability factor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scalability_testing#Outcomes_of_scalability_testing), check out [Performance Testing vs. Load Testing vs. Stress Testing](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/performance-testing-vs-load-testing-vs-stress-testing) guide for more information.

We cannot say how to increase the number of servers without knowing if/how your application is designed for [vertical](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scalability#Vertical_or_scale_up)/[horizontal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scalability#Horizontal_or_scale_out) scalability. You need to ask around how it's going to be set up in production and replicate the same setup in your performance test lab.

Today the majority of enterprises choose packacking the application into a [container](https://opencontainers.org/) and use container management solution like [OpenShift](https://www.redhat.com/en/technologies/cloud-computing/openshift) or [Kubernetes](https://kubernetes.io/) for deploying and managing the product.

Alternatively you can just deploy another instance of the system under test to another "server" and put a [load balancer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Load_balancing_(computing)) in front of it. Once done repeat the same test with the different number of "servers" and compare results.

Comment: With your alternative option, would that be able to be simulated with Jmeter? I have been struggling to find a way for Jmeter to use simulate multiple servers at once